# node: protocol for imports

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I see a new feature in nodejs, the new [node: protocol](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports), but I don't see any use case (other than disambiguating core modules)

for what do we can really really need to use this feature?

Comment: Some discussion here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/38343

Comment: I don't see other than the use case mentioned in the issue descriptions