# Why do some libraries use "import process from 'node:process'" notation?

Tags: node.js

I noticed today that a few node_modules use the notation

```
import process from 'node:process'
```

https://grep.app/search?q=import%20process%20from%20%27node%3Aprocess%27

What is the meaning of this notation and why use this instead of

```
import process from 'process'
```

Comment: Probably the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70777546/node-protocol-for-imports